# c function interface question

Tags: c++

```
extern "C" int func(int *, Foo);
```

This is from a sample code from class. But I don't understand how the interface is working, one with no variable name, the other with no type. How is that going to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When declaring functions you don't need to specify a parameter name, just a type. `Foo` in this case is a type.

`extern "C"` tells the compiler it should use a C-style symbol, which more or less means it won't be using name mangling (which C++ uses to allow multiple functions share a name, but use different parameter sets or namespaces).

Comment: Also, you can't have two `extern "C"` overloads of the same function name.

Answer (score 2):

> one with no variable name, the other with no type. How is that going to work?

In the function declaration (and even in definition), variable names are optional, And in your case, `Foo` is a type, it's not a variable name!

The following program is completely valid even though function `f` mentions no parameter names!

```
int f(int)
{
   cout << "f(int) is called";
}
int main()
{
   f(100);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a function declaration. You don't need to have a variable name. 
The 2nd does have a type, it's Foo.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a `prototype`. That is to say, it's what's needed to call the function, but not the code that says what the function actually does.

All the compiler needs to know to generate the calling code is the types of the arguments of the function, the function name, and the return type. It doesn't need to know the names of the arguments.

The second argument is a `Foo`. That's not the name, that's the type.

Answer (score 1):

By using **extern "C"** you can link a C++ program to C functions.

In your example above, it will turn off *name mangling* for func so that you can link to code compiled by a C compiler.

C++ compilers need name mangling to differentiate between different functions with the same name. Name mangling is the rule according to which C++ changes function names into function signatures before invoking the linker.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is not correct: both parameters have their *type* specified, and none of them has the *name* specified. In this case `Foo` is a type (a `struct`?) already defined somewhere.

That the parameters have no names is not a problem because this is the *declaration* of a function: it only serves to let the compiler know the signature (number and types of parameters, plus return type) of the function. It doesn't matter how the formal parameters are named (or if they are named at all). That information is only useful if you are about to write the function body.